# program to find NIC Details

Tags: java

I used this program to my purpose.
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
class NIC_Details {

String id;
int month[] = {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

NIC_Details() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Your NIC Number \nLike : 000000000V");
    id = input.next();
}

int getYear() {
    return (1900 + Integer.parseInt(id.substring(0, 2)));
}

int getDays() {
    int d = Integer.parseInt(id.substring(2, 5));
    if (d > 500) {
        return (d - 500);
    } else {
        return d;
    }
}

public void setMonth() {
    int mo = 0, da = 0;
    int days = getDays();

    for (int i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
        if (days < month[i]) {
            mo = i + 1;
            da = days;
            break;
        } else {
            days = days - month[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Month : " + mo + "\nDate : " + da);

}

public String getSex() {
    String M = "Male", F = "Female";
    int d = Integer.parseInt(id.substring(2, 5));
    if (d > 500) {
        return F;
    } else {
        return M;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NIC_Details N = new NIC_Details();
    System.out.println("Your Details of Date of Birth from NIC Number");
    System.out.println("Year : " + N.getYear());
    N.setMonth();
    System.out.println("Sex : " + N.getSex());
}
}
```

but when I enter a NIC number like this 93031*******
It gives this details

```
Enter Your NIC Number 
Like : 000000000V
93031******
Your Details of Date of Birth from NIC Number
Year : 1993
Month : 2
Date : 0
Sex : Male
```

Please show me what happen here.

Comment: Is there a problem? Or you just want to understand how this works?

Comment: I want to know where is my fault

Comment: Well, you should tell us if there is an error: What is it? Where is it? Or if the output is wrong, then for what input? And what you expect?

Comment: Enter Your NIC Number Like : 000000000V 93031** Your Details of Date of Birth from NIC Number Year : 1993 Month : 1 Date : 31 Sex : Male

Comment: this is the right details....but I cant get those

Comment: What should it print?

Comment: first 2 digit represent year..next digit show gender..next 2 digit show days...from that i taken out month and days separately but you can see this number 93031****** output month 2 date 0...It should be month 1 date 31

Comment: I think you'd change the method name from `getSex()` to `getGender()`. You know what I mean... :)

Comment: read my answer @facebook-100001774875786

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok, it's your logic that has problem.

Your input is 31 days. Your `setMonth()` method asks if  `days < month[i]`, when `month[0]==31`. 
The answer is no, then you do `days = days - month[i];` which makes `days = 0`, and `month = 2`.

you might want to change your if statement to:

```
if (days <= month[i]) {
```

but that depends on weather 31 days means that 31 days passed, and then your code is good the way it is